# possible for PS script to install PS3 and continue on?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-3.0

I have a PS script that automates server builds. Certain script operations require PS3.

The target environment is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 - which out-of-the-box includes PS2.

Is there a clever way for my script to install PS3 and then continue on ?

The goal is to trigger a single script to build the server.

Comment: You can't "switch" from PS2 to PS3 mid-script. You would have to split your script into 2 portions - one to detect PS3 (or lack thereof), install it and validate that it's installed. Then that script (assuming PS3 installed successfully) would have to kick off PS3, feeding it a script file that represents the remainder of what you need to do. Or you could just change your build process to install PS3 before doing anything else.

Comment: +1 to counter downvote. This is a perfectly reasonable question. The OP said "clever way," which implies he/she is expecting modifications to the suggested way.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's probably a dozen crazy ways to do this. Let's tackle some high level concepts. So, how can might I structure such a script?

```
switch ($psversion.psversion.major) {
  2 {
       # trigger unattended install of powershell 3.0 forcing reboot
  }

  3 {
       # do some powershell 3.0 specific stuff
  }
}
```

So, that's a simple example of a single script that you might run twice, and the second time you run it, it will do something different. The other piece of the puzzle on how to run a script, reboot and continue the script can be read about here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223002/Reboot-and-Resume-PowerShell-Script

Hope this helps,